# refresh changed content of file opened in vi(m)

Tags: vim

I have a config-file that I keep open in vim, but that sometimes gets changed on disk, without these changes being reflected on the terminal. Can I refresh the content on the screen without closing and re-opening the file? If so, how?

Comment: Related: [How can I reload all buffers at once?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/458/467) at Vim SE

Comment: Wrap up: all the answers so far are of "Poll" instead of "Push" style. That is, instead of receiving an external file change event like it was done by other software's similar features, these answers rely on vim actively polling the file change, either manually or triggered by a user action or a timer. The end result is you won't see change refreshed on screen instantaneously.

Comment: Working solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53860166/4814774

Comment: See also: [How does Vim's autoread work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490227/how-does-vims-autoread-work/53860166#53860166) & [Can vim monitor realtime changes to a file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157914/can-vim-monitor-realtime-changes-to-a-file)

Answer (score 536, accepted):

You can use the `:edit` command, without specifying a file name, to reload
the current file. If you have made modifications to the file, you can use
`:edit!` to force the reload of the current file (you will lose your
modifications).

The command `:edit` can be abbreviated by `:e`. The force-edit can thus be done by `:e!`

Comment: The "!" was tripping me, but now it's clear.

Comment: Lose modifications, yes and no.  Crucially, you can still `u`ndo the `:e!`.

Comment: Also, if you want to reload all your buffers, run: `:bufdo e`

Comment: @gerrit: Lose modifications, Definitely yes :) But you can recover the lost modifications by `u`ndoing. :)

Comment: `:w|e` **w**rite *and* **e**dit (reload) :)

Comment: `|` is for chaining commands, and can be interpreted as *then* executing commands in sequential order.

Answer (score 214):

In addition to manually refreshing the file with `:edit`, you can put into your `~/.vimrc`

```
:set autoread
```

to make Vim automatically refresh any files that haven't been edited by Vim. Also see `:checktime`.

Comment: Actually the files are managed by Salt-stack, so I would know when the configuration file would change. But anyway, great tip!

Comment: but it saying "No such file or directory"

Comment: Buyer beware -- If you're working on fresh code and `git pull` be aware you could lose your unsaved changes on screen rather unintentionally.

Comment: @toszter No, Vim will only refresh _unchanged_ buffers. In case of changes, there will still be a query: Keep, or load?

Comment: Thanks! This solution is better because it does not break the folding feature as in `:edit`.

Comment: N.B. autoread [doesn't exactly work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490227/how-does-vims-autoread-work) automatically. You either have to use `gvim`, or run external commands.

Comment: Those using vim inside of tmux can get focus events by using https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events . Otherwise autoread won't help in the terminal unless you somehow call `:checktime`

Comment: `autoread` can be auto-triggered X seconds after the cursor stops moving, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383044/143394).

Answer (score 114):

## TL;DR

Skip to the `Wrap-up` heading for the `vimrc` lines to add to do make your life better.

## Manually

Run [`:checktime`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:checktime)

> Check if any buffers were changed outside of Vim.
>               This checks and warns you if you would end up with two
>               versions of a file.

## Automatically

To do automatically load changes, add in your `vimrc`:

[`set autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27)

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>       it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
>       When the file has been deleted this is not done.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490635/5353461) adds a caveat:

> Autoread does not reload file unless you do something like run external command (like `!ls` or `!sh` etc)

Read on for solutions.

#### Trigger when cursor stops moving

Add to your `vimrc`:

```
au CursorHold,CursorHoldI * checktime
```

By default, [CursorHold](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorHold) is triggered after the cursor remains still for 4 seconds, and is configurable via [updatetime](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'updatetime').

#### Trigger on buffer change or terminal focus

Add the following to your `vimrc` to trigger `autoread` when changing buffers while *inside* vim:

```
au FocusGained,BufEnter * :checktime
```

#### Catching terminal window focus inside plain vim

To have `FocusGained` (see above) work in plain vim, inside a terminal emulator (Xterm, tmux, etc) install the plugin:
[vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events)

On tmux versions > 1.9, you'll need to add in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g focus-events on
```

#### Wrap-up

[Notifications when `autoread` triggers are also possible](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13091/5324).

Here are my `vimrc` lines to implement all the above:

```
" Triger `autoread` when files changes on disk
" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim/383044#383044
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/prevent-focusgained-autocmd-running-in-command-line-editing-mode
    autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI *
            \ if mode() !~ '\v(c|r.?|!|t)' && getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif

" Notification after file change
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/autocmd-event-for-autoread
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

---

<sup>Thanks to [ErichBSchulz for pointing me in the right direction with `au CursorHold`](https://superuser.com/a/1090762/365890).</sup>

<sup>Thanks to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14317/5324) for solving the cmdwin issue.</sup>

Comment: How do you _STOP_ vim from automatically reloading the file every time it changes? It's doing it by default and I don't have a vimrc file, so it must have been recently added to the defaults

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lua version for neovim:

```
-- Triger `autoread` when files changes on disk
-- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim/383044#383044
-- https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/prevent-focusgained-autocmd-running-in-command-line-editing-mode
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'FocusGained', 'BufEnter', 'CursorHold', 'CursorHoldI'}, {
  pattern = '*',
  command = "if mode() !~ '\v(c|r.?|!|t)' && getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif",
})

-- Notification after file change
-- https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/autocmd-event-for-autoread
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'FileChangedShellPost'}, {
  pattern = '*',
  command = "echohl WarningMsg | echo 'File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded.' | echohl None",
})
```